# Proper workout and diet plan for busy person

Tags: diet, workout

I'm 21 and currently working 5x a week 8am - 5pm. I work out 1 1/2 hour after work, every other day 3x a week and eating rice and meat in breakfast and lunch vegetable or fish at dinner. I'm one of those who's skinny fat and trying to get rid of belly fat, but after a month i see no progress on my belly and gained just a bit of muscles. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your first and biggest mistake was expecting visible results after just a month. Whatever results you do gain over such a small period of time, are going to be invisible to the naked eye, simply because you see yourself in the mirror too often.

It seems to me like your diet is good, if you're trying to bulk. I.e. gain weight, both in terms of muscle and fat. And honestly, that's what you should be doing for a good while. Then later, you can cut, meaning lowering your bodyfat percentage.

But really, if you're serious about this, take a before-picture now (if you haven't already), and train for a year at the very least, then start comparing.

Also, log your workouts. For a good long while, the changes won't be visible in the mirror, and the only thing that will tell you that you're making progress, is the numbers you write down during your workouts.